# inserting jQ var inside of another jQ var

Tags: jquery

Can I somehow tell jQ something like this:

```
var $foo = $('#parent #child');
var $boo = $($foo '#grandChild');
```

can $boo find children of $foo?

Comment: `var $boo = $('#grandChild');` should be enough, as that ID can only occur once in the document anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have this:

```
var $foo = $('#parent #child');
```

You can do this:

```
var $boo = $foo.find("#grandChild")
```

or this:

```
var $boo = $("#grandChild", $foo);
```

The second argument to the jQuery function is an optional context that scopes the search to that hierarchy.

Either of these two options will look only at descendants of `$foo` for elements that match the selector.  I generally prefer the `.find()` syntax because I think it makes more readable code that is both more obvious and reads left to right more easily.

If you only wanted to search direct children (not deeper descendants), you could also do this:

```
var $boo = $foo.children("#grandChild")
```

---

If you are truly looking for an id, I would wonder why you're scoping it so much as ids are supposed to be unique in the entire document so

```
var $boo = $("#grandChild")
```

should work if it's an id unless you want to know if a given id is only in a given hierarchy of the page.

Comment: totally agree about `find` prefernce...it's easy to glance over context argument and easier to read left to right